# Why does the console asks for more inputs? C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program where I calculate fees based on the ride type and time the user rented stuff. I came up with the method of how to do it, but when I try to read input the console keeps asking for more input.

```
double computeFee(){
    double fee, hour_rate, minute_rate;
    char ride_type, colon;
    int hour_started, minute_started, hour_ended, minute_ended, total_minutes;
    
    cin >> ride_type >> hour_started >> colon >> minute_started >> colon >>  hour_ended >> colon >> minute_ended;
    total_minutes = ((hour_ended * 60) + minute_ended) - ((hour_started * 60) + minute_started);
    
    switch(ride_type){
        case 'J':
            hour_rate = 500;
            minute_rate = 10;
            break;
        
        case 'K':
            hour_rate = 200;
            minute_rate = 5;
            break;
        
        case 'B':
            hour_rate = 100;
            minute_rate = 2;
            break;
        
        case '0':
            return 1;
            break;
    }

    if (total_minutes < 60){
        fee = total_minutes * minute_rate;
    }else{
        fee = ((total_minutes/60) * hour_rate) + ((total_minutes%60) * minute_rate);
    }
            
    return fee;
}

int main(){
    double total, fee;
    
    computeFee();
    fee = computeFee();
   
    cout << fee;
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You call `computeFee()` 2 times. The first time you throw away the value returned while you print the value the second time.  After you delete the `computeFee();` line you may want to print some instruction for the user what they are supposed to enter.

Comment: `cin >> ride_type` will read the newline character remaining in the input stream from the previous call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `computeFee()`, the function code is executed. In your code, you call it twice, so it will ask you for the input two times. And given that the first time you call it you don't assign it, the first input will be lost.
To make it work the way you want, your `main` code should be:

```
int main(){
    double fee;
    
    fee = computeFee();
   
    cout << fee;
        
    return 0;
}
```